# Table cell width inconsistent

Tags: html, css

How can it be that table  element style width shows one number but its actual width is different? Element style says 175px but actually it is 167px

[image]

Comment: can you provide a snipet that re-produce your problem?

Comment: Tables are very flexible and try to fit themselves in the space available as well as possible. If you give them contradictory sizes, they compensate. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jnd5kb0a/2/). So the question is, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: You have a max width set to 175, but that doesn't set the width, only limit it. The actual width is still 167.

Answer (score -1):

It turned out that if table width is limited then  width does not honor the element style and can be smaller.